# Workflow unable to assign a task

Tags: workflow, permissions

I have a workflow that assigns a task to approver whenever a new item is added to a list. I would like to limit permissions to the task list to make sure nobody makes any changes there except for the approvers. The problem is that when I do this, workflow doesn't seem to be able to assign the task to the approver. It assigns a task on behalf of the task originator (the person who added the item to the list) who doesn't have sufficient permissions for that. How can I empower the workflow to assign task for somebody who wouldn't be able to do so otherwise.

I am using SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using **App Step**. Please enable App Step for workflow.

Then add Assign task portion into App Steps So it is working as **RunWithElevatedPrivileges** in SharePoint Object Model.

Please follow below link for **enable App Step**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify which version of sharepoint you are using or if it is the online version. You should use the impersonation step which is a way to overcome the permission limit. It is inbuilt in the online version. It is still there I believe in the on premise version up to 2013 (not sure about 2016).